# Long list of threats in Windows Defender after using Kali Linux

Tags: windows-10, security, kali-linux, windows-defender

I'm using Windows 10 v1909 and a month ago I downloaded Kali Linux on VMware on my PC.

I recently did a full scan of my PC with Windows Defender, which resulted in a long list of threats (100+, most of them exploits or Trojans). Trying to fix the problem with Windows Defender resulted in contacting a Windows IT tech who helped me delete all the threats.

- Could the threats originate from Kali Linux exploits being interpreted as threats?
- Could Windows Defender detect BurpSuite, which I also used, via wifi?

Comment: It would appear you downloaded the threats in Windows 10. Perhaps give us one exploit you downloaded and then lets see what happens when this is downloaded in Kali. I am posting this from Kali.

Comment: Kali is a pen test OS, so the OS contains exploits to be used in penetration testing and it's drive storage _(likely a VHD file in this case)_ should never be scanned with any type of AV or anti-malware scanner - one of its many tools is Metasploit, which is a collection of malware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kali linux `.iso` file is detected as malware by Windows Defender, and for good reason: it contains malware that you can use to infect computers. Try removing the `.iso` file and running Windows Defender again.